# how to cache user likes and favourites using redis?

Tags: mysql, redis

Suppose I need to do user likes cache since there could be many users hit like button or dislike button in a short period of time.

My idea is that create a mysql table with fields including user_id, liked_object_id, liked_object_type, create_time and (user_id, liked_object_id, liked_object_type) as composite key. When a user hit like button, insert a record to the table, and when a user cancel the like, delete the row from the table. This mysql table is for persisting the data.

And then put the redis in, when user hit the like button, first add a hash object to the redis database, and put the key of that hash object to a set called "cached_keys", so I can grab those hash objects more easily. If the user cancel the like, then the key of the cancelled hash object is moved from "cached_keys" to another set called "deleted_keys" which all the cancelled like's keys is in. Why I do this is I could track which like object is added or deleted when I write all the data in the redis back to mysql table after certain period of time. Except that persisting to mysql, I only do query and write to the redis.

There are other problems. Like query all all likes of a certain type of object and of one user. in order to do this, I need create many redis sets, which namespace is combine of object_type and user_id, and store the all the corresponding object_id in the set, and modify them along with other set like "cached_keys" and "deleted_keys". Another similar case is query all users who liked a certain object.

Another problem is do join query. Since the data is cached in the redis, it's difficult to do paged join querys to the mysql likes table, for example query a list of objects, sort by it's like count. I have to get all the objects from mysql to the memory, then get likes count from redis and sort them, then page the results. And If I want to do some query of one type of objects which one user has liked, I have to get all the keys from the redis and use a "IN".

Doing it like this feels not the right way to do it. Every time the persist happended, its gonna write all the records to the database at once, doesn't feel like it could scale well, as well as the join query.

How could I improve this, or should I do it in a completely different way? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd suggest keeping redis as a cache to check before doing SQL, and a place to push SQL results. I'd avoid anything that tries to use the redis cache results in the SQL, it sounds too easy to get wrong.

Comment: Regarding "Like query all all likes of a certain type of object and of one user." did you consider adding RediSearch module so you'll be able to support such query?

Comment: @Guy Korland I checked the RediSearch doc, it says it could do Prefix based searches. I think it's userful there, but it's kind complicated I don't understand if it could solve the other problem

Comment: @danblack What do you mean exactly a cache to check before doing SQL?  If don't use redis cache in SQL, does that mean write to the redis and mysql table at same time?

Comment: updates: delete applicable redis cache entries (or manipulate if easy), do SQL. For reads: check redis and return results if exists, fall back to SQL, deliver results to user, push results to redis,